# Angular - TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, google-authentication, angular2-observables

While attempting to resolve an order of execution issue with Google authentication (i.e., waiting for an async call to complete), I've run into this odd error. Everything works if I don't add `.subscribe`, but I'm trying to wait until the Google pop-up window has returned before continuing on with other things. I'm trying to change "signIn()" to return an observable (it used to not return anything), I've run into this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined.

Subscribe part where the error happened:

```
this._authService.signIn().subscribe(
      value => console.log(value),
      error => console.error(error),
      () => console.log("done")
    );
```

And the altered service method:

```
signIn(): Observable<boolean>  {
    const signOptions: gapi.auth2.SigninOptions = {scope: SCOPES };
    if (this._googleAuth) 
      Observable.fromPromise(this._googleAuth.signIn(signOptions))       
        .subscribe(response => {
        var user:any = response;
        if(response === true) {
          this.handleSuccessLogin(user);
          return Observable.of(true);
        }
        else {
          return Observable.of(false);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      console.error("Google Authentication not initialized");
      return Observable.of(false);
    }
  }
```

Update: Here's my version returning directly from signIn. As per the first suggestion:

```
signIn(): Observable<{}>  {
    const signOptions: gapi.auth2.SigninOptions = {scope: SCOPES };
    if (this._googleAuth) {
      return Observable.fromPromise(this._googleAuth.signIn(signOptions))       
      .map(response => {
        var user:any = response;
        if(response === true) {
          this.handleSuccessLogin(user);
        }
        return response;
      });
    }
  }
```

FYI: My previous question that led to this change: [Angular - waiting for Google authentication to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46030619/angular-waiting-for-google-authentication-to-complete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning result from an asynchronous call won't work as expected. You can change the `this._googleAuth` branch to return an Observable directly and do things you want at `map` part:

```
return Observable.fromPromise(this._googleAuth.signIn(signOptions))       
         .map(response => {
           var user:any = response;
           if(user) {
             this.handleSuccessLogin(user);
             return true;
           } else {
             return false;
           }
         });
```

refer **[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/k3EGsae1Z9u8o6OdrQEY?p=preview)**.

Comment: thanks and I appreciate the example. I'm trying your suggestion but it's not returning anything at all and the handleSuccessLogin() call isn't firing either. See my update. Did I mess up something?

Comment: @beachCode you should still keep your else branch

Comment: @beachCode change `signIn(): Observable<{}>` to `signIn(): Observable<boolean>` and make sure your `this._googleAuth.signIn(signOptions)` can get response back.

Comment: I actually started with that and got this error: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Comment: @beachCode foe this error, just change `signIn(): Observable<{}>` to `signIn(): Observable<boolean>`

Comment: @beachCode I just mock your `googleAuth` with a `setTimeout`(both are asynchronous). If `handleSuccessLogin` is not fired, that means `googleAuth` doesn't get response back.

Comment: @beachCode sorry I'm going out for some hours from now. If you have further problems, I'll answer you on the phone. Maybe you can still ask others from more help. good luck. :-)

Comment: thanks again. Just so you know, changing to signIn(): Observable<boolean> is the change that caused the error I quoted. I added the else block back and it's not getting fired either.

Comment: @beachCode I got it. the `googleAuth. signIn` will return `GoogleUser` not `boolean`, see my updated answer(also the updated plunker demo). This way you can still use `signIn(): Observable<boolean>`